# How to tell if my main activity was killed by the system

Tags: android, android-activity

In my app I have one main activity and second activity. My second activity is transparent and the main activity is shown under.

My problem is that sometimes when the user gets back to the app strait to the second activity, the system has destroyed the main activity and now the main activity is not shown throw the transparent part.

I want to make sure that if My main activity is destroyed by the system, then I should know about it or the app should restart from the main activity.

Is it possible? How?

Comment: `onSaveInstanceState` of main activity will be called when it is killed beneath you transparent activity, you can add put your restarting logic there. Please note, your main activity can be killed even if transparent activity is not paused. I think what you would like to achieve is not the best UX, how would you like to present your interruption/restart to the user ?

Answer (score 0):

When your second activity goes into `onPause`, kill it with `finish()`.

Then use your `MainActivity` as a 'controller' and when `onResume` is called , i.e. when a user returns  to your app start an `Intent` for your `SecondActivity` , that way you can always guarantee they are both there

Comment: The second activity is kinda havy so It's not a good idea to restart it evey time the user pauses it.  I need to restart only when the main activity is kiiled.

Comment: well try another platform because that's not how Android works. A more positive answer is: move the heavy lifting into the MainActivity and have the SecondActivity as a view on this data. *there is always a solution*!

Comment: I understand what you are saying. the second activity is a webview that is loading a web site. as you see I cant have it on the main activity. But I found a way. I am using a static boolean var in the main. If the main activity is killed this static variable will return false.  Do you see any reason why it shouldn't work?

Comment: Static variables live outside the scope of your activity instance, so that won't work. Just do what I said and enable caching in your WebView. You can always do some prefetching as well